# Specman - Assign uint decimal number to sequence

Tags: sequence, variable-assignment, decimalformat, specman

I have the following sequence:

```
extend CONFIG_ADC_CLK ocp_master_sequence_q { 
    divide_by : uint(bits:4);
    align_by : uint(bits:4); 

    body()@driver.clock is {
        var div : uint(bits:3);
        case divide_by {
            1   : {     div = 0;    };
            2   : {     div = 1;    };
            4   : {     div = 2;    };
            8   : {     div = 3;    };
            16  : {     div = 4;    };
            default : { dut_error(divide_by," is not a legal Clock division for ADC");  };
        };

        gad_regs.gad_clk_gen.clk_algn = align_by;
        gad_regs.gad_clk_gen.clk_dev = div;
        do WR_REG seq keeping {.reg==gad_regs.gad_clk_gen;};
    };
};//extend CONFIG_ADC_CLK ocp_master_sequence_q {
```

In the test I use the sequence :
    do CONFIG_ADC_CLK seq keeping {.divide_by== 3;.align_by==0;};

For some reason the compiler refer the number of the field `divide_by`as hex number instead of decimal.
How can I ensure that it will refer it as decimal?

Comment: Can you please clarify - what do you mean by "the compiler refer the number as hex number"? In what way does it refer it as hex? At least `3` has the same meaning in hex and decimal, so what is working wrong?

Comment: Or maybe you mean the way in which the number is **printed** (as part of the `dut_error`) ?

Comment: @Yuri Tsoglin - Yes, I mean the way in which the number is printed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not related to sequences and not related to how numbers are assigned to fields. It's just about how numeric values are *formatted* in printing and string operations. The actual value of a field has nothing to do with how it is printed.

By default, `dut_error()`, `message()`, `out()`, `append()` and other string formatting routines use the current setting of `config print -radix`. So, you probably have it set to `HEX` in your environment.
If you need this specific `dut_error()` to always use decimal format, no matter what the config setting is, you can use `dec()`, like this:

```
dut_error(dec(divide_by)," is not a legal Clock division for ADC");
```

By the way, when using the second variant of those routines, such as `dut_errorf()` or `appendf()`, you can determine the radix by providing the right `%` parameter, e.g., `%d` for decimals or `%x` for hexa, for example, the above `dut_error()` might be rewritten as:

```
dut_errorf("%d is not a legal Clock division for ADC", divide_by);
```

Here, you can also use `%s`, in which case the config radix setting is still used.